# iOS - Create Database Schema (Run code only once)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database

I'm using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) for my iPhone App database and i want to create the database and tables schema only once.

How can i run OBJC code when the user installs or updates the app?

Kinds Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a boolean value in `NSUserDefaults` - `NSUserDefaults` is only reset when the user deletes the app, so you have some code that executes if a particular boolean value is not found in the user defaults (and then saves that value after execution to prevent it from being run again).

That will cover your plain 'run code once upon install' scenario - you can achieve the same for updates with a similar approach, but utilising the `CFBundleVersion` variable (which will be different for each version of your app).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might not want to think about executing something during upgrading, because it's not possible. Like @lxt suggested, you can store a value in the preference to indicate database version, but it might not be bulletproof.

A common approach to solve this problem is to use self-built meta-data. When you first created the database, you should create an extra table named `"metadata"` or `"properties"`, with two varchar columns, `"name"` and `"value"`. You insert one row, `("database_ver", "1")`.

In your database layer (or adapter) class, you create an "open" method to handle opening. Within this method, you first run `select database_ver from metadata;` to check database version. If nothing is fetched, you run table creation scripts, and insert database_ver=1 row.

Later on if you upgraded your table format, provide `alter table` statements for each version, and run them based on `database_ver`. For installations after the upgrade, you can use the updated `create table` statements, then set `"database_ver"` to `"2"` (or above) directly, without going through `alter table`.

Compared to storing value in the preference, it's actually more common to store it in the database itself. Because even if the user backed up the file somewhere, or skipped a version, you can still tell the format of the database by its metadata table.

FMDB has no problem running such mechanism.