# update sqlite table on next release ios

Tags: ios, sqlite, sql-update

I have created a table on my app. On the next build I am adding some more column and changing the name of one column.
Because the table is already created it will not create the table again, hence the changes are also not get reflected.

How to deal with this problem? please help me..

Comment: Use alter table sql command and change the table structure, or you can use NSFileManager to delete the old database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136256/updating-new-version-to-app-store-with-different-sqlite-db-structure